# bpfilter kernel log

Tags: networking, kernel, network-manager, iwlwifi

I am using ubuntu 20.04.3 with a kernel 5.14.11-051411-generic. When I examine the kernel log, I find numerous and seemingly useless messages such as:

`tail -f /var/log/kern.log`

```
Oct 19 18:04:03 hugo-MS-7978 kernel: [9221.242399] bpfilter: read fail 0
Oct 19 18:04:03 hugo-MS-7978 kernel: [9221.341973] bpfilter: Loaded bpfilter_umh pid 37308
Oct 19 18:04:03 hugo-MS-7978 kernel: [9221.342409] bpfilter: read fail 0
Oct 19 18:04:03 hugo-MS-7978 kernel: [9221.404678] bpfilter: Loaded bpfilter_umh pid 37310
Oct 19 18:04:03 hugo-MS-7978 kernel: [9221.404824] bpfilter: read fail 0
Oct 19 18:04:03 hugo-MS-7978 kernel: [9221.486405] bpfilter: Loaded bpfilter_umh pid 37312
Oct 19 18:04:03 hugo-MS-7978 kernel: [9221.486831] bpfilter: read fail 0
Oct 19 18:04:03 hugo-MS-7978 kernel: [9221.558156] bpfilter: Loaded bpfilter_umh pid 37314
Oct 19 18:04:03 hugo-MS-7978 kernel: [9221.558584] bpfilter: read fail 0
Oct 19 18:04:10 hugo-MS-7978 kernel: [9228.831964] [UFW BLOCK] IN = enp0s31f6 OUT = MAC = 01:00:5e:00:00:01:c4:e9:0a:3a:2c:34:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=30112 PROTO=2
```

How do I fix this problem or disable the bpfilter?

Comment: Try iptables in legacy mode. See [this](https://wiki.debian.org/iptables).

Comment: I don't understand how iptables work, since what I find in / usr / sbin are symbolic links to / etc / alternatives, which again has symbolic links to / usr / sbin apparently of the legacy type

Comment: Oh! If you are already using iptables in legacy mode, then try it not in legacy mode. Note that `UFW` is just a front end for iptables.

Comment: I think it is a bug in the kernel, since the problem is described in the compiled kernels at www.kernel.org.

On my computer, with the wifi and ethernet connections turned off, the bpfilter messages:

Loaded bpfilter_umh pid 113000
[22218.336885] bpfilter: read fail 0

Still appear

Comment: I tried to switch to iptables-nft but I don't know the procedure and the instructions on the internet are confusing for me

Comment: The solution was to downgrade the kernel to 5.14.1-051401-generic

Comment: Interesting. I could not find the problem described on kernel.org, please give a link. You should write an answer to your own question for others to see.

Comment: I found these three links: https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20200727141337.liwdfjxq4cwvt5if@wittgenstein/

https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20200727132855.GA28165@lst.de/

https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20200727104636.nuz3u4xb7ba7ue5a@wittgenstein/

Comment: On the same thread https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20200730060654.GA17803@lst.de/ ...